# Oracle Managed Data Access Returning Statement Causes ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

Im trying to implement an insert statement using a returning statement to return the auto incremented id of the new row. Doing this causes an `ORA-01722: invalid number` exception even though I am pretty sure that i setup all the params correctly.

Im sure it is the return variable that is causing the problem since without it everything works just fine.

Here is the Oracle command text:

```sql
INSERT INTO ANGESTELLTER (
    NAME,
    VORNAME,
    GEHALT,
    KOMMISSION,
    CHEF)
VALUES (:NAME, :VORNAME, :GEHALT, :KOMMISSION, :CHEF)
RETURNING ID INTO :generatedID
```

And this is the way i setup the generatedID return parameter:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add("generatedID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
command.Parameters["generatedID"].Size = 25; // Someone posted that this is needed for the query to work in their case
```

The Oracle Database type is simply `Number` and when I query the ID a decimal is returned in C#.

I tried running the command in SqlDeveloper where it actually worked
I tried changing the database type to number and using decimal since before we were using `Number(5,0)` and Int32, but that also didnt work.
I tried using ParameterDirections.Output but that did not change anything.
I tried the command in SqlDeveloper where it did work with the data provided to the insert command.
I also tried settings a default value for the parameter so that it isnt null.

Comment: You might try a 10046 trace at level 12 and examine the trace file to get the exact bind values the database sees. That might show a misalignment or unexpected value and help drive toward root cause on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Paul W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20542862/paul-w) I now know that tracing is a thing which was actually very informative but did not reveal the error.

So I tested the command manually in my code, creating all parameters like this:

```cs
const string insertCommandReturning = """
                                      INSERT INTO ANGESTELLTER (NAME, VORNAME, GEHALT, KOMMISSION, CHEF)
                                      VALUES (:NAME, :VORNAME, :GEHALT, :KOMMISSION, :CHEF)
                                      RETURNING ID INTO :generatedID
                                      """;

var cmd = OracleDatabase.CreateCommand(insertCommandReturning);
cmd.BindByName = false;
cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "John";
cmd.Parameters.Add("VORNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Doe";
cmd.Parameters.Add("GEHALT", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 50000;
cmd.Parameters.Add("KOMMISSION", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 0.1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("CHEF", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = null;
cmd.Parameters.Add("generatedID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
decimal returnval = ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["generatedID"].Value).Value;
```

This worked flawlessly, but basically doesn't differ from my generated parameter assignment.

But then I remembered that I am not adding my parameters in this order since that is not the way my classes are reflected and the generatedID is added first. And the default parameter binding is not via name but via order, which I thought wasn't the case when using names for the parameters.

Therefore, this code doesn't work:

```cs
const string insertCommandReturning = """
                                      INSERT INTO ANGESTELLTER (NAME, VORNAME, GEHALT, KOMMISSION, CHEF)
                                      VALUES (:NAME, :VORNAME, :GEHALT, :KOMMISSION, :CHEF)
                                      RETURNING ID INTO :generatedID
                                      """;

var cmd = OracleDatabase.CreateCommand(insertCommandReturning);
cmd.BindByName = false;
cmd.Parameters.Add("generatedID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "John";
cmd.Parameters.Add("VORNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Doe";
cmd.Parameters.Add("GEHALT", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 50000;
cmd.Parameters.Add("KOMMISSION", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 0.1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("CHEF", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = null;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
decimal returnval = ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["generatedID"].Value).Value;
```

But this code does:

```cs
const string insertCommandReturning = """
                                      INSERT INTO ANGESTELLTER (NAME, VORNAME, GEHALT, KOMMISSION, CHEF)
                                      VALUES (:NAME, :VORNAME, :GEHALT, :KOMMISSION, :CHEF)
                                      RETURNING ID INTO :generatedID
                                      """;

var cmd = OracleDatabase.CreateCommand(insertCommandReturning);
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("generatedID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "John";
cmd.Parameters.Add("VORNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Doe";
cmd.Parameters.Add("GEHALT", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 50000;
cmd.Parameters.Add("KOMMISSION", OracleDbType.Double).Value = 0.1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("CHEF", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = null;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
decimal returnval = ((OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["generatedID"].Value).Value;
```

All I had to do was enable `OracleCommand.BindByName`